Splide slider touchpad vertically working to slide items in slider but not working horizontally
https://development-self.vercel.app/
This is my live nextjs build. I have used splidejs Slider to show tags right below the header. slider is working good.
But I just want to slide it using touchpad horizontally not vertically.
I have tried custom javascript codes but they are not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
